# Getting Error while testing pagespeed in google's pagespeed insight

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I am getting the an error while testing the pagespeed in Google's insight:

Lighthouse returned error:

> FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the
> page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that
> the server is properly responding to all requests

URL: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=meandersquest.com

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This seems to be because your redirect from `http` to `https` takes 16 seconds. Something isn't right there, fix that and PSI should work. This is because one of the tests PSI performs is that `http` redirects to `https`, because it doesn't get a response within a few seconds when it tries the `http` version it fails.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Is the redirection of http to https is bad and unnecessary? Any heads up how to fix this up? Thanks.

Comment: no you need the redirection. Without seeing your setup it is hard to diagnose why it is taking so long. Normally you just put an entry in your `.htaccess` file to redirect all traffic from `http` to `https`. You need this but normally it takes milliseconds not seconds so something is wrong (potentially could be a DNS issue). If I get chance later I will try and have a dig around for you and offer some more detailed information rather than general guidance.